# Does Debian install *important* packages if standard system utilities is not selected?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

Per these:

[What's the consequences if I don't install the "standard system utilities" of Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307600/whats-the-consequences-if-i-dont-install-the-standard-system-utilities-of-de)

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-priorities

there are three priority levels of packages:

- `required`
- `important`
- `standard`

I understand that `required` packages are installed by default. `standard` packages are optional and can be selected during installation.

What about the `important` ones?
Are they also installed by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important packages will be installed by default.

[7.7. What is an Essential, Required, Important, Standard, Optional, or Extra package?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html#priority)

> Important packages should be found on any Unix-like system.

> Other packages which the system will not run well or be usable without will be here. This does NOT include Emacs or X or TeX or any other large application. These packages only constitute the bare infrastructure.